# How to rename multiple files, contained in multiple sub-directories

Tags: linux, loops, rename

I have a parent directory that contains multiple subdirectories, and each subdirectory has multiple files. For example:

```
Sub-directory_1
xyz1.fq.gz
xyz2.fq.gz

Sub-directory_2
abc1.fq.gz
abc2.fq.gz

etc.
```

I'd like to add the subdirectory name, as a prefix, to each file in each subdirectory.

I've been trying to do this with a loop that uses subdir and FILENAME, but can't get it right. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use find command:

```
$ find . -type f -exec bash -c 'mv {} "$(dirname {})/$(dirname {})_$(basename {})"' \;
```

Comment: This almost did what I wanted, except that all of the files were duplicated and saved with the new name while the original files remain.

Comment: I changed the 'cp' to 'mv', and it worked. Thanks heaps!!

Comment: Oh Yes I'm sorry, I have use cp for test before answer.